# No 3D acceleration in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with latest Vmware Workstation

Tags: 14.04, hardware-acceleration, vmware-workstation

I installed the latest version of vmware workstation (10.0.2) in ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have the following problem:

[image]

I use the open source driver "Radeon" (Galium 0.4) and Mesa 10.1.0.

**My graphics card:**

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: X.Org OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD
RS780 OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa
10.1.0 OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40 OpenGL core profile context flags: (none) OpenGL core profile
extensions: OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0 OpenGL shading
language version string: 1.30 OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:


lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 VGA

01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[AMD/ATI] RS780D [Radeon HD 3300] [1002:9614]
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:834d]
Kernel driver in use: radeon 01:05.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon (HD) 3000
Series] [1002:960f]

glxinfo | grep -i render

direct rendering: Yes
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780
GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp,
GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp,
```

I tried to install `driconf` and changed `Enable S3TC texture compression`...by default is `No`, and also edited the `.vmx` file, adding the line:

```
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"
```

But it doesn't work.

I checked if this package is in my system:

```
libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
```

I think it is a free implementation of the texture compression library for Mesa. This package is installed by default on Trusty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Your Ubuntu video driver does not support 3D.  You need to install the opensource driver or the ati catalyst driver

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this other question incredibly useful. [Enable 3D HW acceleration on VMWare Workstation 10 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537787/enable-3d-hw-acceleration-on-vmware-workstation-10-on-ubuntu-14-04)

The winning answer, https://askubuntu.com/a/537870/318507 which worked great with Workstation 12 on my Ubuntu 16.04 install.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
sudo chmod +x ./VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.2-1744117.x86_64.bundle
```

This is to give execute permission to bundle file. Now you can run the file:

```
sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.2-1744117.x86_64.bundle
```

Comment: The OP is having problems getting 3D support in VMware Workstation, not problems executing the installer. If you believe re-installing will fix the OPs problems I would suggest stating that more clearly in your answer.