# Enable 3D HW acceleration on VMWare Workstation 10 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware, 3d, hardware-acceleration, vmware-workstation

I am trying to enable hardware accelerated 3D graphics in a Win 8.1 VM in VMware Workstation 10.0.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Trusty Tahr) to play the game Smite smoothly. I have checked that the HW acceleration works in Ubuntu:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.2.2

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

In VMware Workstation, on the VM under "Virtual Machine Settings" -> "Display" -> "Accelerate 3D Graphics" is checked.

[image: Screenshot]

But while booting the VM, it says "No 3D support is available from the host".

[image: Screenshot]

How comes VMware does not detect HW 3D acceleration? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to enable 3D support in VMware: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_vidsound_d3d_enabling_vm.html

Comment: @madmike, I think I did this correctly -- see the first screenshot. But thanks for the in-depth link!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Edit the file `~/.vmware/preferences` and look for a line that starts with `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers`, if it is not present - you can add it into the file.

This should be changed to `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"` 
(note the double quotes around TRUE)

Comment: Thanks, @charles-green - that seems to work. The game is down ATM, but the VM boots up without complaining about missing 3D support.

Comment: Works here, too. Thx!

Comment: Just wanted to note that this also works in Workstation 11. By default, the `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers` parameter is not present in the preferences file, but adding it does work. Thanks.

Comment: Not work in vmware 10

Comment: @WHK Does your hardware support 3D, and do you have appropriate drivers loaded in the host operating system?

Comment: Work in VMware Workstation 12.

Comment: Same is needed for the free vmware-player

Comment: VMWare Workstation 12 - works.

Comment: Thanks! Works great with VMWare Player 12, Ubuntu 15.04, and Intel HD 4600 Graphics!

Comment: This worked great for getting my VM to boot with accelerated graphics on a system that has the Nvidia "Optimus" technology that dynamically switches between Intel and Nvidia graphics.

Comment: This caused my VM to crash upon booting into a graphical environment. Workstation 12.

Comment: +1 for putting it in `~/.vmware/preferences` instead of the VMX file. That way the setting is scoped to the host with the "bad" video driver and not to the individual VM.

Comment: Works in VMware Workstation 14.1

Comment: Worked for VMware Player 14.1.1 on Fedora 27

Comment: Works on Workstation 14.1.2 on Ubuntu 18.0.4

Comment: Works on Workstation 15.0.2 build-10952284 on Arch, too.

Comment: Should use `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"`

Comment: worked like a charm in 2019 on VM Workstation with Win10 guest on Linux Host

Comment: Worked in workstation 16.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: I can confirm it works on Ubuntu 22.04.01 and VMWare Workstation 16 Player

Comment: @StackMaster Thanks - it's been 6 years, and it's good to know this still works.

Comment: It's worth asking if this expose a vm an additional security risk? Or increment the surface of attack one can use to potentially escalate from the virtual machine?

Comment: @user3450548 My understanding (and I may well be incorrect) is that blacklisting a driver or module is done primarily to prevent that module from interfering with the system in some unwanted manner.  Not that it may be a security problem, but that it may not play well with others.

Comment: @CharlesGreen are you talking about the guest system or the host system?

Comment: @user3450548 The setting is one for the host system, allowing the host system to utilize the drivers within VMWare.  I should point out  that not long after this was written, in 2015, I ceased using VMWare and moved to QEMU

Answer (score 18):

Add `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"` in the .vmx file.

It has worked for Linux Mint Cinnamon as host with kernel 3.16 and Debian 8.2 Cinnamon as guest.

Comment: +1 for likely relevant answer. While [this forum post in 2013](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-and-cloud-90/enabling-3d-and-hardware-acceleration-in-guest-vms-on-linux-host-4175503780/) seems to agree, [this Ask Ubuntu post](http://askubuntu.com/q/450383) indicates it is not always the case. This depends on video driver support too.

Comment: I didn't have a Preferences file so I modified the VMX on Workstation 12. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Note for those migrating XP guests from VirtualBox to VMWare Workstation 12 Player Linux 64-bit following a Sysprep process - adding this option to my .vmx file fixed an issue where the mouse pointer was stuck in a single place on the screen and couldn't move. After adding this line the mouse was working again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to add `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"`to my virtual machine (.vmx) file

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens This is required for some of the VirtualBox machines to load drivers that are sometimes a little problematic.  There's quite a bit of information over at [https://communities.vmware.com/thread/573123](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/573123)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dual graphics cards, the warning implies that the independent graphics card is not available for VMware. Setting `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers` indeed solves the problem, but a better way to solve this is to run VMware via:

```
optirun /usr/bin/vmware
```

Or, for convenience, you can change your `.desktop` file and use `/usr/bin/optirun /usr/bin/vmware %U` as the command.

This solution provides better performance.

See https://www.tiger2doudou.com/doku.php?id=linux:tools:virtualize:vmware_3d_hw_acceleration_with_bumblebee

Answer (score 0):

on Debian 10 we face the some problem, we solve it by adding the `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"` 
to the vkx file

Answer (score -1):

For me (Ubuntu 18.04, Intel graphic, VMware v16, Windows10), to activate 3D acceleration it was necessary to add mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE". I have choosed to add this to my virtual machine (.vmx) file.

Without this, if 3D acc. is activated, W10 login screen, text and icons on popup notification and menus are totally not readable! All works fine if 3D acc. is not activated

After some hours : eclipse repeatedly freeze while debugging java application, task manager : csrss.exe process consuming #10% CPU.
3D acc. disactivated => same problem
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE" deleted => OK

So don't use mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"