# Ubuntu 16.04 Running unbearably slow

Tags: dual-boot

My Ubuntu installation is running slow as if it was the 90's.

Now, when I say slow, I mean *slow*. Whenever I want the super bar to open, it takes approximately five seconds to open, and I can see the box being drawn line by line. This takes approximately one second. However, the mouse moves perfectly smooth and no problems occur there.

Now, the specs and the setup:
Intel Core i3-6100 2@3.8Ghz (+Hyperthreading)
AMD XFX Radeon RX 460 W/ 4GB GDDR5 VRAM (PCI-E@16x)
MSI H110m Gaming Motherboard
2x 1 TB (931 GB) HDD 7200 RPM +SATA 6 GB/S
16 GB DIMM DDR4 @2133MHz

---

The Botched Setup:
I have Windows 10 on the first HDD with Ubuntu on the second, and to get to Ubuntu, I just run the second harddisk with boot override.

I have a confession, I installed Ubuntu with VMWare, and linked the Virtual Machine to my blank second harddisk to install, and opened it when it was done, and saw this problem.

P.S. Xorg (currently) is taking 98.3% of my CPU, and 1% of my RAM (160 MB)

Comment: Oh! I used ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso to install

Comment: Do a proper dual boot installation in UEFI mode and it should be fine.

Comment: This is my second installation

Comment: If you did the same way why were you expecting different results? And what did you do to "install Ubuntu with VMWare"? Why don't you do install as it should be, as in my first comment?

Comment: Because I ran out of CDs

Comment: The problem is that you installed Ubuntu that was being tricked to use a virtual display device controlled by vmware.  Then running that version directly on your system most likely gives trouble. You installed it for a different (virtual) machine and it is actually quite remarkable that it even starts at all. Try this with some other OS-es and see it epically fail within seconds. Re-install Ubuntu without vmware directly so it can configure properly during setup and it will give you the performance you expect. Good luck!

Comment: *Because I ran out of CDs* and you still live in the 90s, I suppose. Now, jokes aside, do yourself a favor, get a cheap USB thumb drive (2GB should be enough) and install it *comme il faut*. I agree with @E.F.Nijboer, it's most likely *not* using the correct graphics driver.

Comment: My thumb drive is dead because my cousin left it open, so I'm just going to buy a CD-RW off of Amazon, Peace guys! (question closed)

Comment: FOR EVERYONE'S SANITY: YES, I WILL INSTALL IT PROPERLY

Comment: @CelticWarrior: The installation medium has absolutely no bearing on the system performance *after* the installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable 3D HW acceleration on VMWare Workstation 10 on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/537787/enable-3d-hw-acceleration-on-vmware-workstation-10-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its more a guess as I am having a similar slow down in a system. The reason there is the graphics which is using not the correct hardware accelerating driver, but a generic one which is using the CPU to emulate the things the GPU could to. Also the high load in xorg hints to that. I could imagine that your somewhat exotic installation procedure prevented the graphics driver from a correct installation. 
So before doing anything else I would suggest to reinstall the graphics driver. I can not walk you through thid, but you should find plenty of descriptions by searching for your card type.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that's what I did, it said I had a weird graphics card I've never heard of, so I installed the right driver and it works

Comment: error - deleting comment